# need help to handle multi upload file selenium webdriver on mac

Tags: selenium-webdriver

i have worked code to upload file. in this case, i have file to upload like identity card and earnings photo. but somehow on upload file no 2 , selenium not uploaded it properly. its like selenium not select the file even my finder(window) already openend.

if i disable code upload file 1, my code for upload file 2 will be error too

please review my below code :
- upload file 1(identity card)

```
//no 1
driver.findElement(By.id("uploadBtnOther_1")).click();
        StringSelection ss = new StringSelection("/Users/prasetyo/Documents/Test/file upload/KTP-600x416.jpg");
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(ss, null);

       //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys
        Robot robot = null;
        try {
            robot = new Robot();
        } catch (AWTException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(TestScripts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
        robot.delay(500);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.delay(500);
        robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
        robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

        Thread.sleep(3000);
```

- upload file 2 (earnings photo) *cannot upload

  //upload GAJI
  driver.findElement(By.id("uploadBtnOther_2")).click();
  StringSelection gaji = new StringSelection("/Users/prasetyo/Documents/Test/file upload/bug.jpg");
          Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getSystemClipboard().setContents(gaji, null);

  ```
     //native key strokes for CTRL, V and ENTER keys

      try {
          robot = new Robot();
      } catch (AWTException ex) {
          Logger.getLogger(TestScripts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }

  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
  robot.delay(500);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_G);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_G);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_V);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.delay(500);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  robot.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE);

  Thread.sleep(3000);
  ```

thanks expert

Comment: do u have a publish URL to replicate the above issue..also it is advised to use avoid Robot for upload case..selenium can upload files on input control whose type is file

Comment: I had answered a similar question in the past, and it did work for me. See if this helps you. **[http://stackoverflow.com/a/27505018/4193730](http://stackoverflow.com/a/27505018/4193730)**

Comment: got the solution, i create paramater for every upload, 


try {
        robot1 = new Robot();
    } catch (AWTException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(TestScripts.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_META);
robot1.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_META);
robot1.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);
robot1.delay(500);

when upload process done, click java aplet to continue next upload